# FHIR Resource Search Parameters

Tags: search, hl7-fhir

I'm looking for a flat file or other machine processable file which has (at least) a list of FHIR resources along with the search parameters and include parameters that each resource type should support in a RESTful environment. The documentation is great, but building code items by hand for the many resource types (which will likely change) is tedious to say the least. Has anyone compiled such a file or know if one is available?

Answer (score 3):

This file is always current: http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/profiles-resources.xml. it includes all the defined parameters for each resource type and their properties.

We're working on making the definitions of the search parameters processible themselves (not just the definition of the parameter, but of what it indexes). That's still in process

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much, I'm not sure why I never found that source file. As for making the search parameters more processible, you could consider xpath expressions. It would be very helpful, as most tools for generating code could easily use it.

Comment: I can't think why that had never occured to me, other than that I use json equally much. If you contribute any xpaths, I'll build them in.

Comment: I have been adding xpath values to a local copy of profiles-resources.xml and would be glad to share them when I'm finished. What is the best way to submit it? Also, I had a recommendation for a resource modification, where is the best place to present it for consideration?

Comment: Comments on resources - the FHIR mailing list (see http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=FHIR_email_list_subscription_instructions). For the xpaths - maybe the mailing list, or perhaps attach them here?